# request not defined inside forms.py class (forms.Form)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.1

The error

```
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

My forms.py

```
class PersonForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    job_title = forms.CharField(required=False)
    status = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=Person.STATUS_CHOICES)


    project = Project.objects.get(users=request.user, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=project.companies.all(),required=False)

    new_company = forms.CharField(required=False)
    note = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
class PersonCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'person/person_form.html'
    form_class = PersonForm
    success_url = '/project/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        cleaned_data = form.clean()

        active_project = self.request.session['active_project']

        project = Project.objects.get(users=self.request.user, pk=self.request.session['active_project'])

        if cleaned_data['name']:
            person, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
                name=cleaned_data['name'], 
                job_title=cleaned_data['job_title'], 
                created_by=self.request.user,
                status=cleaned_data['status'], 
                project=project
            )

            if cleaned_data['new_company']:

                company, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=cleaned_data['new_company'], project=project, created_by=self.request.user)
                company.persons.add(person)
                company.save()

            if cleaned_data['note']:
                person.note_set.create(content=cleaned_data['note'], created_by=self.request.user)
                person.save()

            if cleaned_data['company']:

                company = project.companies.get(name=cleaned_data['company'])
                company.persons.add(person)
                company.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.POST.get('next', '/project/' + str(self.request.session['active_project']))
```

I want to filter the `queryset` on the `forms.ModelChoiceField` field `company`. Based on the companies of the project the user has access to. How would I do that? Can I access `request.session` data as well here?

Comment: You do that inside a method, probably `__init__`

Comment: this is basic python, your `project` property uses `self`, you can't do that at the class level.

Comment: Updated to 'request'

Comment: Can you post the view you use to handle the form? do you use a create view or do you use your own function for this?

Comment: Updating it to `request` doesn't help at all, you still don't have that at the class level.

Comment: Added my view @Sergio. Yes I know Daniel, but that is my question

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that like this, because Django forms don't have access to the request at all.

So the best approach I can think of is to pass the user to the form and then use the data when initialized.

First you have to pass the user and pk in the view.

views.py:

```
# ...
form = PersonForm(user=request.user, pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Then in your form, you can catch both kwargs and update the project with the correct value,

```
class PersonForm(forms.Form):
    # your form fields code ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # get the user and pk
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        pk = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
        # update project field
        super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project'] = Project.objects.get(users=user, pk=pk)

        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Answer (score 0):

In class-based views to update Form kwargs:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({"request": self.request})
    return kwargs
```